# Не работает SOCKS5 прокси через обратный ssh тунель

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, ssh, openssh, networkx

Есть две сети, одна находится за кучей NATов (PC0 [192.168.1.29]), другая с выделенным IP адресом, через которую проброшен сервер (PC1 [192.168.1.49]). (На обоих ПК стоит UBUNTU).
Логины одинаковые на двух ПК.
На PC0 я выполняю команды:

```
# Поднимаю SOCKS5
ssh -D 6000 login@127.0.0.1 -f -N -g
# Туннелирую его на PC1
ssh -g -f -N login@192.168.1.49 -R 6001:127.0.0.1:6000
```

В итоге на PC1 я могу изменить настройки браузера и всё будет хорошо, всё работает, даже DNS через SOCKS5 нормально работает. Проверил, могу ли подключиться из внешней сети, всё получилось.
Через какое-то время снова попробовал, на локальной машине работает, с другой сбрасывает соединение.
Как правильно туннелировать подобный SOCKS5 через обратнй ssh?
Большое спасибо за ответы!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=ServerAliveInterval

Comment: Не много не понимаю, причём тут время ожидания? На локальной машине всё работает, через socks5 прокси на 127.0.0.1:6001
Проблема в том, что если я к этому порту проброшу через роутер порт, то соединения будут сбрасываться. Как понимаю, только 127.0.0.1 разрешенный получается, ведь если изменить на 192.168.1.49, то тоже не выйдет соединиться с прокси.

Comment: *Через какое-то время* «не работает». вот для этого и придуманы все эти опции {client,server}alive{inteval,countmax}.

Comment: Понял о чём вы. Но я же несколько раз запускал, тем более в данный момент работает через PC1, но только через PC1... А мне как раз нужен доступ к PC1 из вне и он точно был, далее перезапустил сервер, хотел потренироваться в создании туннелей, но вот тут меня встретил облом, когда всё сделал так же (я надеюсь), больше из вне не смог подключиться, а только локально из машины PC1.